# Lubuntu desktop not loading on admin user

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, lxde, administrator

My lubuntu crashed, and after reboot, when I log in on any of my administrator accounts, it would show the default wallpaper and the mouse pointer. Also, can't open the terminal or any other keyboard shortcuts.
I can log in using the guest account, but it doesn't have permission to do most actions.
I were also able to log in my account using openbox mode, but most admin actions were supressed too.
I can't create a new user (I was hoping the new user could log in OK, since the guest could.
The only option is to re-download and re-install lubuntu, but I don't have a fast enough web connection (and I would also lose all my data).
What can I do to reset my user, or create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, can you get to command prompt? If so, try adding a new user by doing:

`sudo useradd username -D`

Comment: That's what I was looking for. In openbox mode, I tried to find a command for creating users in terminal, but didn't find it. Thanks. Also, is there a command for deleting users?

Comment: Yeah, `sudo userdel username` and don't forget  `sudo rm -rf /home/newuser` to remove their home directory.
Don't forget to mark it as accepted if it worked for you :)